# Cannot find name 'line' - d3 line chart

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

While trying to integrate d3 line chart, the following error is shown.
I'm using https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-to-create-a-line-chart-using-d3-js-4f43f1ee716b for creating the line chart.

```
g.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "steelblue")
.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
.attr("d", line);
```

This gave the error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'line'.
```

Then I added:

```
var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date)})
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.value)})
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date }));
   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value }));
```

to my typescript, which resulted in the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'date' does not exist on type '[number, number]'
```

Code for line:

```
var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(d.date)})
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.value)})
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date }));
   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value }));
```

Any experts in d3.js..?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: json file with two values

Comment: I'm not sure this really needs an expert in `d3` as it's a question about TypeScript. I guess what do the type bindings define `d` as when you're `x()` function is called?

Comment: I dont have much idea about Typescript, followed the code from https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-to-create-a-line-chart-using-d3-js-4f43f1ee716b

Comment: `console.log` your variable `data` and see if the structure is an array of objects or an array of `[number,number]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using typescript, you have to tell `d3` the type you are passing to the `line` generator:

```
var line = d3.line<MyDataType>()
  .x(function(d) {return x(d.date);})
  .y(function(d) {return y(d.value);});
```

Where *MyDataType* is the definition of one of your datum, something like:

```
interface MyDataType{
    date: Date,
    value: number
}
```

Comment: Showing error TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: @VishnuNair, is your date not a Date?  According to the tutorial you are attempting to follow, it should be.